# Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with a discrete joint distribution, and let $Z = r(x, y)$ for some function $r$.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Prove that the conditional distribution of $Z$ given $X = x$ is the same as the conditional distribution of $r(x, y)$ given $X = x$.

Comment: Should it be $Z=r(X,Y)$ ?

Comment: Indeed.  rakhilu, *please* check your capitalisations.  It *will* affect the interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but if Z = r(x,y), then the conditional distribution of Z will be equal to the conditional distribution of r(x,y) because they are the same thing.